# vue js - can't find child component template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

After reading the vue.js docs I just jumped into components.
I want to create a custom (local) input component that emits an event to the parent on `keyup`, but I have two problems. (see code example at the end of the post)

**[solved] 1. I already get an error when I register the child component that says**

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <InputTest>
       <Root>
```

I guess it's a complete no-brainer, but I just don't get it.

**[solved] 2. The child event doesn't even fire**
Before abstracting and simplyfing the code for this question I tried to create the same behaviour with single-file (.vue) components. With SFCs the template compiles / mounts successfully, but the child component events doesn't fire. Obviously I can not tell for sure if this problem will occur in my provided example as well, but I'd guess so.

**EDIT 1: Solved problem 1**
My child-component should be an object instead of a vue instance. I updated the code for that. I also changed the `onChange` method from lambda to function, as `this` doesn't point to the vue instance in a lambda.

**EDIT 2: Solved problem 2**

> [There may be times when you want to listen for a native event on the root element of a component.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)

Apparently the native modifier can only be used on components and not on native elements. Removing the modifier fixed the problem. I changed the code accordingly.

**CODE**

```js
const inputText = {
        data () {
            return {
                model: ''
            }
        },
        template: '<input type="text" v-model="model" @keyup="onChange">',
        methods: {
            onChange: function () {
                this.$emit('update', this.model);
            }
        }
    };

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data () {
            return {
                txt: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onUpdate: function(txt) {
                this.txt = txt;
            }
        },
        components: {
            'input-text': inputText
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input-text @update="onUpdate"></input-text><br>
    {{ txt }}
</div>
```

Comment: You have created another Vue instance, instead of a component. Check: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration | Remove the `new Vue()` part and your code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two vue instances. You can create a component as a simple object and use it in your vue instance

```js
const inputText =  {
  template: '<div> <input type="text" @keyup.native="onChange"> </div>',
  methods: {
    onChange: () => {
      console.log('onChange');
      this.$emit('update')
    }
  }
  
  }
 

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<input-test @keyup.native="onKeyup" @update="onUpdate"></input-test>',
  methods: {
    onUpdate: () => console.log('onUpdate'),
    onKeyup: () => console.log('onKeyup')
  },
  components: {
    'input-test': inputText
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: ohhhh thanks, that works. But now still onChange and onUpdate are not fired, only onKeyup. Got any idea why that is?

Comment: Yeah, I see more mistakes on your code. But what do you need on update for? if the value in the input changes?

Comment: Yeah. Kinda when the model changes. So I could also use a watcher on model, but thought it would be more elegant to use a listener

Comment: Yeah, this is tricker than I thought, but basically, I don't think you can use @change like that in vue. You have to use a model and a watcher ... just tried this https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/33/ it needs a clean up but I'm at work.. let me know if you can't figure it out

Comment: Fixed it, see my edit for details. Thanks again for your help!